# How to stop shell buffers echoing directory path when `cd` into it?

Tags: shell

When `cd some_directory` then <kbd>RET</kbd> in `shell-mode`, `some_directory` is printed in the echo area.

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(shell-dirtrack-verbose nil))
```

---

`shell-dirtrack-verbose` is a variable defined in ‘shell.el’.

Its value is t

If non-nil, show the directory stack following directory change.

This is effective only if directory tracking is enabled.

The `dirtrack` package provides an alternative implementation of this feature.  See the function `dirtrack-mode`.

You can customize this variable.